# Generating an electric field for a colloid thruster

Tags: propulsion, engines, ion-thruster, electric-propulsion

I was wondering how the electric field in an electrospray thruster works to ionize particles and propel a micro spacecraft. I was thinking of possible circuits but I wasn't sure what it could look like. 
I am familiar with the design of the needles and the fuel container but I don't know how the extractor electrode fits in.